# AWS Budget setup error -- There were errors while creating this budget. Please try again

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to create a budget in aws with three alert of 80 percent, 50 percent and 20 percent threshold. The steps taken is as below

```
1. In the navigation pane, I choose Budgets.
2. At the top of the page, I choose Create budget.
3. For Choose budget type, I choose Cost Budget.
4. For budgt period I choose monthly
5. Budget effective date to be recurring budget
6. Budget amount to 50 dollar
7. Gave the name AWS_BGT_MONITOR
8. Now Simply I set up three alert 80%, 50% and 20%
9. While choosing the three alert I enter my email id in notification preference.
10. Please note I do not set up any SNS QUEUE

Every time when I try to create the budget, it simply throw an error
**There were errors while creating this budget. Please try again.**
```

I tried with different browser and different threshold and still facing same issue. As the error message is not very informative I am not able to resolve.

Can any body suggest If I am missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem got resolved. The biggest problem here was the AWS UI error response was not very informative. The only problem was I do not had billing policy added to my role. Once the admin added billing policy I was able to create the budget.